# How do you add a predefined const as a object property

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I don't know if its even possible but I'm wondering if you can add a const as an object property for an object.

So for example something like this:

```
const x = "age";

let array = {
name : "Tom",
x: "15";
}
```

So, in my case adding a new property to the object called 'age'. Where `x` is the variable that was already defined.

This is probs a dumb question but thanks in advance :)

Comment: Using object indexer (I think that's what it's called) `[]` you can: `let array = { name: 'Tom', [x]: '15' };`

Comment: oh right, thank you so much! @nbokmans

Answer (score 1):

try this code :

```
const x = "age";

let array = {
name : "Tom",
[x]: "15";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)

```js
const key = "age";
const value = 15;

let object = {
  name : "Tom",
  [key]: value
}

console.log(object);
```

But you can also take advantage of the [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) notation by declaring a property that will take the name of the variable passed as well as assign its value to the property.

```js
const age = 15;

let object = {
  name : "Tom",
  age
}

console.log(object);
```